# Android linux container for ubuntu host

Tags: android, linux, containers

I am working on linux container with android as guest OS and Ubuntu as host OS.

Till now I was able to run a ubuntu,fedora OS as guest OS running as linux container 
inside ubuntu host OS as the template for installation of the given OS is present as 
template in lxc tool itself.
I used https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/singlehtml/lxc_quickstart/lxc_quickstart.html link as a reference.

I have following questions

1)How can we make our own template of android OS to make it run inside linux container

2)Will this also require some kernel patches to be installed on our host linux kernel

3)Please note that host OS is ubuntu and guest OS is android. As I have already found the link http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/AndroidContainer which is not exactly what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone has worked for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to modify the android kernel to make it possible to boot GNU/Linux. In this way, we can have a linux running with supporting android. Then i think some work like [this](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/23/lxc-1-0-some-more-advanced-container-usage/) can be done.